# Count no. of times: average from timea-timeb is below average from timec-timed the next day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I have a query which is stumping me in Excel:

I have a range of temperature data, recordings from every minute of every day for 3 months.

I want to find out how many times the average temperature from 20:30-21:30 on each day is lower than the average temperature from 01:00-02:00 the following morning (about 5 hours difference).

If that is difficult to understand here is a "logic formula":

> count(averageTemp(dateX(timeA-timeA+1))<(averageTemp(dateY(timeB-timeB+1)))

Here's a sample of the data as a screenshot:

[image]

Please help me out, this one has me scratching my head.

Comment: Image: https://imgur.com/a/pfe5fmM

Answer (score 1):

Enter this as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) and change "122401" to the last row number of your data range:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(AVERAGEIFS(C2:C122401,B2:B122401,"<="&TIMEVALUE("21:30"),B2:B122401,">="&TIMEVALUE("20:30"),A2:A122401,ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&A122401)))<AVERAGEIFS(C2:C122401,B2:B122401,"<="&TIMEVALUE("02:00"),B2:B122401,">="&TIMEVALUE("01:00"),A2:A122401,ROW(INDIRECT(A2+1&":"&A122401)))),0))
```

This assumes that the first set of temperatures from 01:00-02:00 does not have a matching set from 20:30-21:30.

Comment: I think I would have put ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&A122401-1) in the first averageifs to get n-1 averages where n is the number of days, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: @TomSharpe Leaving the -1 off lets the formula get the last calculation in case the data end before 20:30 on the last day (I think). Otherwise the `IFERROR` takes care of the comparison with mismatched arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would input a flag in column D that takes value 1/0 whether the time is in the frame you are interested in.

So input in D2 = IF(OR(AND(B2<21:30,B2>20:30),AND(B2<01:00,B2>02:00))),1,0).

Then I would go in column C and check if in D I got 1, input a simple IF statement to check for the temperature.

Let me know if it works!